# amortized complexity of merging overlapping intervals in a stream

Tags: algorithm, merge, stream

For the problem of merging intervals in a stream of data, one approach
is to store each incoming interval in a min heap (sorted by interval's start). Each `add(interval)` will add interval to heap and also merge it with overlapping intervals if needed.

It is said that the complexity per `add` can be worse than logn however the amortized time will be logn.

I couldn't really develop the intuition as to why this is true. I know that if merges are necessary `add(interval)` can take longer than logn, because we need to pop elements from heap, but how can I prove to myself (intuitively or mathematically) that the average will be logn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question, because lots of amortized algorithms have similar simple proofs of their costs:

The `add` operation takes **O((m+1) * log N)** time, where **m** is the number of merges that need to be performed.

Each merge, however, will *remove* a previously added element.  Since an element that is added can only be removed once, we can we transfer the **O(log N)** cost of merging and removing that element to the `add` operation that created it, and we arrive at the amortized cost of **O(log N)** per `add`.

Comment: I should also point out that merging intervals on pop leads to a much simpler implementation, although it may take more space.  The costs for extra pops per operation can similarly be transferred to the adds.

Comment: moving the delete-and-merge cost to the add operation means `add` is now O(2logN)?

Comment: O(2 log N) = O(log N)